# Is it true that the dimension of an array is determined the moment the array is created, and cannot be changed later on?

Tags: c++, c

```
int main()
{
    int a[3]={1,2,3};

    int *b;

    b=&a[10];

    printf("%u\n",b);

    printf("%d",*b);

}
```

I thought that the above program would give me an **error** as `a` is a collection of only *3 data items*, and `b=&a[10];` by this `b` stored the address of the *11th data member* of `a`. But in place of error it gives the address of 11th data member.

Size of the array is 3 and but it can store the variables beyond of its size! so how does it possible?

Comment: It's not giving you the *address of 11th data member*. It's giving you the random content of memory beyond the end of the array.

Comment: I did not get you, Sir can you please explain it little bit? @KenWhite

Comment: I explained it. So does the linked post.

Comment: local arrays must have constant size at compile-time as you do with `int a[3]`. `b` is not an array but it is a pointer to an integer (element[10]) and as you can see `a[10]` is not an element of the array so you have UB.

Answer (score -7):

Yes, this usually works, because C and C++ don't check these things.

BUT this may cause exception on different operating systems, and may also cause an exception on your own code sometime in the future. This is an `unknown` behavior stuff, and you should avoid it.

Comment: "Yes, this usually works" - No, it does not! It is un**defined** behaviour.

Comment: NMDV, yet aside from "this usually works" is an overstatement and 
"C ... don't check" which is better as "C is not specified nor required to check", the answer does not address the title question:  "dimension of an array ... cannot be changed" which is certainly false with code lacking UB.

Comment: I think your edit was too much about you, and was essentially "trust me, I am right". Answers should focus on code, not the author. Hope that helps!